# TYPO3 Site Error Handling does not work on an Exception

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I configured following Error Handlers:

```
errorHandling:
  - errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=639'
  - errorCode: '0'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=640'
```

When calling a page and proudcing an Exception, the default TYPO3 
`Oops, an error occurred!`appears, but not the defined page.

Whats my mistake?

Comment: Enable `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` first of all so you will find exact issue with redirection

Comment: Setting this parameter changes nothing. Just shows "Oops, an error occured"

Comment: By the way, not the redirect throws an error - it is an anohter issue with extensions that could happen. But i don´t want that the visitor gets an Oops, i want to define a custom page